# Are old Android WebViews a risk to Activesync email, and how do I block old devices?

Tags: email, mobile, virus, exchange

I'm concerned that old versions of Android may be hacked through unpatched WebViews (in PhoneGap and other apps), exposing Activesync email data, and other sensitive information.

To mitigate this, I'm considering blocking old devices from accessing the server.

- Is this a legitimate concern?
- How would I block these devices?

This concern stems from [this Forbes article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/01/12/google-webview-updates-quietly-killed-for-most-androids/) saying Google will not be deploying patches to old phones, and will rely on 3rd parties instead.  Given that Android malware [has been increasing](http://www.scmagazine.com/android-malware-rises-300-percent-report-says/article/390903/) in frequency, this may become an urgent situation

Comment: Wow that's a quick end of life for an OS.  Considering a lot of applications wrap WebViews of their mobile site this is a little concerning to me.  User agent strings contain the Android version generally.  You might be able to block on that.